# How to style (with CSS) "20201231123456" into "20201231-123456"?

Tags: css

The "20201231123456" is a version identifier, to be displayed as static text in a page element. It's rather hard to parse visually, and I was wondering whether I could **use pure CSS to display it split into its date and time components**; that is, without needing to modify the actual value in the HTML source?

I've tried to search, but either I get results from 2011 saying it's not possible but someone's working on it, or results suggesting putting every character into its own span.

Is there a modern solution to this seemingly simple idea?

**Bonus:** To complicate matters, this goes into a long table with other stuff -- and some of the version identifiers are 5-digit numbers rather than date-times, but they are displayed in the same type of HTML element. Could the HTML element's styling accommodate both formats, so that "54321" remains as is, but "20201231123456" still becomes "20201231-123456"?

Comment: CSS is a technology for presenting elements. In this situation what are the marked-up elements you are looking to present?

Comment: it's just a straightforward `<div>target text here</div>`

Comment: but instead of "target text here", we have this "single-word" number that I want to chop up

Comment: I think this gets to the heart of the issue. The smallest atomic particle that you can style in CSS is an element. In your example immediately above, you can style `<div>`. If you mark it up as `<div><span>target</span> <span>text</span> <span>here</span></div>` then you can style any or all of the `<span>` elements. You can't style something that it less than an element.

Comment: The only counter-examples I can think of (which are both quite specific) are the CSS pseudo-elements [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) and [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).

Comment: As @Rounin said you can't do it with CSS because it's not the language for that. You'll need JS to do that. A for loop iterating through all the list elements and then checking the length of the list entry's string and inserting the dashes at the right spots

Comment: @Rounin please make an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here there is a **CSS-only solution** that works for both long (14 characters) and short values (less than 14 characters):

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  width: 15ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: 20ch;
  text-shadow: 
    /* the date */
    -20ch 0, -40ch 0, -60ch 0, -80ch 0, -100ch 0, -120ch 0, -140ch 0,
    /* the time */
    -159ch 0, -179ch 0, -199ch 0, -219ch 0, -239ch 0, -259ch 0;
}
```

```html
<div>20201231123456</div>

<div>12345</div>
```

The idea is using monospace font (same width all characters) and the `ch` unit that will allow you to move the characters around a little in an *orderly* fashion. Set a fixed width to the container, and then space them enough so they are out of the box. Finally, use `text-shadow` to project one character at a time.

I know, it may be tedious (and a bit silly), but it kind of works :)

But you wanted it with a dash, for that, use a pseudoelement like `::before` or `::after`:

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  width: 19ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 20ch;
  text-shadow: 
    /* the date */
    -20ch 0, -40ch 0, -60ch 0, -80ch 0, -100ch 0, -120ch 0, -140ch 0,
    /* the time */
    -159ch 0, -179ch 0, -199ch 0, -219ch 0, -239ch 0, -259ch 0;
}

div::before {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  left: 8ch;
}
```

```html
<div>20201231123456</div>
```

---

And now for the cherry on top: use the pseudo-elements of the box to draw the lines and colons to format the date completely. Although then it won't work on smaller dates, just on long ones:

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  width: 19ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 20ch;
  text-shadow: 
    /* the date */
    -20ch 0, -40ch 0, -60ch 0, -79ch 0, -99ch 0, -118ch 0, -138ch 0,
    /* the time */
    -157ch 0, -177ch 0, -196ch 0, -216ch 0, -235ch 0, -255ch 0;
}

div::before {
  content: "-:";
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 3ch 0, -12ch 0, -9ch 0;
  left: 4ch;
}
```

```html
<div>20201231123456</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome solution!

In addition with help of `:before` we can manage hyphen
`div:before {
content: '-';
position:absolute;
left:8ch;
}`

Comment: @SergeP Thanks for the suggestion. I totally forgot about that part :)

Comment: Honestly I still don't get how your last solution works :) In `:before` third shadow value applies to the last char ":"? But how they placed inside the date and time?

Comment: @SergeP an element can have multiple text shadows. By spacing the letters more than the size of the actual string (15 = 8 date + 1 space + 6 time), I ensure that only one letter/number of the text-shadow will be visible within the div. So I have one text-shadow for each letter, and move it in the right position. It is not ideal, but it works for this case without that much code.

Comment: Looks like [decent browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=ch-unit) for the 'ch' unit, but partial in the old Internet Explorer family (which shouldn't come to a surprise to anyone.) Very cool solution; learned something new today. :)

Comment: This is completely awesome. I'll hold off accepting your question for two more hours, so that I may award you a bonus. I am deeply grateful.

Comment: Why did you specify the font-family to be monospace _twice_ ?

Comment: @KlaymenDK browsers handle monospace font size in a funky way, adding monospace twice is a "hack" to make it handle them properly. You can read a more detailed explanation on [this article](http://code.iamkate.com/html-and-css/fixing-browsers-broken-monospace-font-handling/).

Answer (score 1):

With CSS alone I don't think it's easily doable,
**using JavaScript** [String/slice <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) it's quite simple:

```js
const str = "20201231123456";
const [date, time] = [str.slice(0, 8), str.slice(8)];

console.log( `${date}-${time}` )
```

Or like:

```js
const str = "20201231123456";
const res = /^(\d{8})(\d+)$/.exec(str).splice(1).join('-');

console.log(res)
```

---

#### Use-case example:

Say the *version IDs* are inside a specific element like `<span>` or `<td>` with a class `.vid`:

```js
const prettyVID = el => {
  const str = el.textContent.trim();
  const [Y, M, D, h, m, s] = str.match(/^\d{4}|\d{2}/g);
  const ISO8601 = `${Y}-${M}-${D}T${h}:${m}:${s}Z`;
  const custom  = `${Y}${M}${D}-${h}${m}${s}`;

  el.title = new Date(ISO8601).toLocaleString('en', {timeZone: 'UTC'});
  el.textContent = custom;
}


document.querySelectorAll('.vid').forEach(prettyVID);
```

```css
th, td {padding: 8px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>App name</th><th>Version (Hover to see date)</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Lorem</td><td class="vid">20201231091015</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ipsum</td><td class="vid">20200224123456</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is that CSS is not the right technology for this task.

CSS has many presentational capabilities, ***but***... the smallest atomic particle that you can style in CSS is an HTML element like `<div>` or `<span>` or `<strong>` etc.

If, for example, we take the following `<div>` element:

```
<div>target text here</div>
```

we can use CSS to present the `<div>` in any number of ways.

And if we mark it up as:

```
<div><span>target</span> <span>text</span> <span>here</span></div>
```

then we can style any or all of the `<span>` elements.

But we can't style any part of the markup that is smaller than an element.

---

**N.B.** We *could* argue there are a limited number of (quite specific) exceptions to the final statement immediately above, including the CSS pseudo-elements `::first-letter` and `::first-line`.

---

### What approach can we adopt if we can't use CSS?

As @BastianSpringer notes in the comments above, Javascript has the capability to produce the effect you want to achieve.

**Working Example:**

```js
let numbers = [...document.getElementsByClassName('number')];

for (let number of numbers) {

  numberText = number.textContent;

  if (numberText.length > 8) {
    let numberArray = numberText.split('');
    numberArray.splice(8, 0, '-');
    numberText = numberArray.join('');
    number.textContent = numberText;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="number">54321</p>
<p class="number">20201231123456</p>
```